# What is the fastest way to go through an array / table with numeric indices?

Tags: lua

If i have an array with numbered indices in lua and need to go through every entry at least once, is it faster to use a numeric for loop or a generic for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Semantical Difference

```lua
for i = 1, #t do end
```

**is not the same as**

```lua
for i, v in ipairs(t) do end
```

the latter does not rely on `#t` and respects the `__ipairs` metamethod (although this is deprecated and the `__index` and `__newindex` metamethods should be used instead).

Assuming no metamethods are set, `ipairs` will simply loop until it encounters a `nil` value. It is thus roughly equivalent to the following loop:

```lua
local i, v = 1, t[v]
while v ~= nil do --[[loop body here]] i = i + 1; v = t[i] end
```

This means there are two things it doesn't have to do:

- It does not determine the length. It won't call a `__len` metamethod if set. This might theoretically result in a better performance for lists which reside in the hash part (where Lua has to determine the length through a search). It could also improve performance in cases where the `__len` metamethod does costly counting.
- It does not have to loop over `nil` values. The numeric for loop on the other hand might loop over arbitrarily many `nil` values due to how the length operator is defined: For a table `{[1] = 1, [1e9] = 1}`, both `1` and `1e9` are valid values for the length. This also means it's unclear what it does, as the exact length value is unspecified.

The latter point in particular means that in pathological cases, the numeric for loop could be *arbitrarily slower*. It also allows for mistakes, such as looping over (possibly long) strings instead of tables, and won't trigger an error:

```lua
local str = "hello world"
for i = 1, #str do local v = str[i] end
```

will loop over only `nil` values (as it indexes the string metatable) but throw no error.

I also consider `ipairs` to be more readable as it makes the intent clear.

## Performance Difference

For non-pathological cases (lists residing in the list part, no "holes" (nil values), no odd metatables), the numeric for loop can be expected to run marginally faster, as it does not incur the call overhead of the for generic loop you'd be using with `ipairs`. This ought to be benchmarked on different Lua implementations though:

- PUC Lua 5.1 to 5.4
- LuaJIT 2.1.0

In practice, the costs of looping will often be negligible compared to the cost of the operations performed within the loop body. Results may vary depending on other factors such as operating system or hardware.

#### Rudimentary Benchmarks

```lua
print(jit and jit.version or _VERSION)

-- Fill list with 100 million consecutive integer values
a = {}
for i = 1, 1e8 do a[i] = i end

local function bench(name, func)
    func() -- "warmup"
    local t = os.clock()
    for _ = 1, 10 do func() end
    print(name, os.clock() - t, "s")
end

bench("numeric", function()
    for i = 1, #a do
        local v = a[i]
    end
end)

bench("ipairs", function()
    for i, v in ipairs(a) do end
end)
```

Conducted on a Linux machine.

```
Lua 5.1
numeric 54.312082   s
ipairs  63.579478   s
Lua 5.2
numeric 20.482682   s
ipairs  32.757554   s
Lua 5.3
numeric 14.81573    s
ipairs  23.121844   s
Lua 5.4
numeric 11.684143   s
ipairs  24.455616   s
```

Finally, LuaJIT:

```
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
numeric 0.567874    s
ipairs  0.70047 s
```

**Conclusion: Use LuaJIT if possible and stop worrying about micro-optimizations such as `ipairs` vs. numeric for** (even though the latter may be slightly faster). Something as simple as an `assert(i == v)` will already cost as much as the loop itself (even if `assert` is `local`).

Answer (score 1):

In this exact case it would be faster to use a numeric for loop. But not by much and in my testing it is more prone to load differences on my system.

Numeric Loop

```
a = {} -- new array
for i = 1, 10000000 do
    a[i] = 10000000 + i
end

local startNumLoop = os.time(os.date("!*t"))

for i = 1, #a, 1 do
    local value = a[i]
end

local stopNumLoop = os.time(os.date("!*t"))

local numloop = stopNumLoop - startNumLoop 

print(os.clock())
```

Result: 1.379 - 1.499

Generic Loop

```
a = {} -- new array
for i = 1, 10000000 do
    a[i] = 10000000 + i
end

local startGenLoop = os.time(os.date("!*t"))

for index, value in ipairs(a) do

end

local stopGenLoop = os.time(os.date("!*t"))

local genLoop = stopGenLoop- startGenLoop

print(os.clock())
```

Result: 1.568 - 1.662

Tested with lua 5.3.6 win32 binarys from lua.org

This was just a question i had where i didn't find the answer fast enough. If it is in fact a duplicate feel free to mark it so. :)

Comment: The comparison is not fair as you don't retrieve the value in the former `for`-loop. You'd probably find the difference to be negligible if you had a non-empty loop body BTW. What about Lua 5.1 to 5.4 and LuaJIT?

`ipairs` should only have a minor function call overhead. I'd even expect LuaJIT to inline it.

Comment: the empty loop is intended, so no time in there is spend on commands/functions. Is there a difference in print time in regarding in which loop it is placed?
Tested with lua 5.3.6 win32 binarys from lua.org (added in answer)

Comment: nvm, now i see what you meen with retrieve. will edit my answer :)

Comment: Still not quite fair (this time biased towards `ipairs`), as you assign to a global (as opposed to a local) variable.

Comment: i like it every time more, learning is fun :)
I got nothing against pairs or ipairs or for. Its just a question i came up with in a game lua file and didn't find any satisfying an quick answer. 
This is btw. the reason why not luaJIT. The game doesn't have it, so i'm stuck with basic lua.

Comment: Then that's the main performance issue (a factor of 2x - 5x is to be expected) - not `ipairs` vs numeric for loops. Use whatever you find more readable (I think `ipairs` is better in that regard) and don't worry about the performance - this really is just a micro-optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Especially for loops where is necessary to remove/change the current key/value pair i prefer the fast countdown method...

```
for i = #tab, 1, -1 do
 if (tab[i].x > x) then
  table.remove(tab, i) -- See comments
 end
end
```

...for example in LÖVE [love2d] between two frames.

Comment: Why not simply `tab[i]=nil` instead of `table.remove(tab)`?

Comment: Iterating in reverse order is useful when you want to selectively delete items; you can implement an `ipairs`-like iterator for that too though, which many libraries do.

For your example, why not simply replace the table with an empty one: `tab = {}` instead of removing all elements?

Comment: @lhf - To keep it simple ;-) - I have a third one: ```table.remove(tab, i)``` that in countdown mode or reverse order always returns the last one. @LMD you are right too. Of course i use conditions between ```do``` and ```end``` and normally that checks dont trigger all. Therefore its better to improve my post with an ```if```.